# Sobi2 plugin interface

Tags: joomla

is there any plugin interface for sobi2 ?
if yes where I can find the documentation ?
I am not able to find any documentation on sobi site.

Answer (score 0):

sobi2 is pretty straightforward:
http://sigsiu.net/manual/

That will get you pretty much anywhere you need.  What questions did you have specifically relating to it?
I've used Sobi2 a number of times with great success - cloning installs to change the name creates some interesting challenges, but most other things are pretty straightforward and can be figured out with a little trial/error.

Comment: Ah, okay!  You may want to check on their forums - I know the developers (as well as others) are really helpful!  They're on there frequently.
http://www.sigsiu.net/forum/